# Open modal when click on button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have this code :

```
   <sepa-modal
    ref="sepaModal"
  />
  <b-card
    id="show-btn"
    class="card-modal"
    @click="openSepaModal()"
  >
  </b-card>


  openSepaModal() {
    console.log(this.$refs);
    this.$refs.sepaModal.show();
  },
```

SepaModal :

```
<b-modal
class="sepa-modal-edit"
id="sepaModal"
centered
top
no-fade
static
size="lg"
ref="modal"
hide-footer>
...........
```

I have the error : `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.$refs.sepaModal.open is not a function"`. I tried with `this.$refs.sepaModal.show();` (the same error). Very strange because I put a console.log and I have `sepaModal` in `refs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.$refs.sepaModal.$refs.modal.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different (cleaner imo) approach. `b-modal` can be controlled thanks to the `v-model` directive.
So your `SepaModal` should have a prop that will take a boolean, and pass it as a v-model to `b-modal`. With this you don't mess with the component's instance and have full control over the data that toggles your modal

```js
<template>
  <sepa-moda :is-opened="isOpened" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  /* ... */
  data() {
    return {
      isOpened: false
    }
  }
  methods: {
    openSepaModal() {
      this.isOpened = true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The modal:

```js
<b-modal
v-model="isOpened"
class="sepa-modal-edit"
id="sepaModal"
centered
top
no-fade
static
size="lg"
ref="modal"
hide-footer>
```